# How can we get timestamp date difference and show format like (d.m.Y) using php?

Tags: php

How can take date difference using php?

I tried some code but showing error: `date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, object given`

This is the code I have tried

```
$checkin_from = 1502143200000
$reserve_to = 1502229600000
$days       = round(abs(strtotime(date_format($checkin_from , 'd.m.Y')) - strtotime(date_format($reserve_to, 'd.m.Y'))) / 86400);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: Sticking random functions together is not really a good approach to programming. And formatting a date difference as "d.m.Y" is somewhat weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are using milliseconds instead of seconds first you have to divide them by `1000` to convert it into valid `timestamp` of seconds.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/802460)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$checkin_from = 1502143200000/1000;
$reserve_to = 1502229600000/1000;

$dateObj1= new DateTime();
$dateObj1->setTimestamp($checkin_from);

$dateObj2= new DateTime();
$dateObj2->setTimestamp($reserve_to);

$result=$dateObj1->diff($dateObj2);
print_r($result->d);
```

Comment: `DateTime` can handle UNIX timestamps directly, going through `date` first is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Sahil Gulati I tried to but getting and error. "Object of class MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime could not be converted to int"

Comment: @samsam Can you tell me on which line you are getting this error because in my above post i haven't used anything related to mongo

Comment: @Sahil Gulati, Dates are getting from mongodb and that date is storing in to variable `$checkin_from` and `$reserve_to`.

Comment: @samsam Make sure you are getting this `1502143200000` in `$checkin_from`?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
<?php
$checkin_from = '1502143200000';
$reserve_to = '1502229600000';
$datediff = $reserve_to - $checkin_from;

echo date('Y-m-d',$checkin_from)."\n";
echo date('Y-m-d',$reserve_to)."\n";
echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

**Output**

```
1935-04-17
1938-01-11
Total Days: 1000
```

Demo :  [Click Here](https://eval.in/802594)

Comment: There are 1000 days between these two timestamps…?!

Comment: Please check output I have converted `strtotime()` to date its like difference of more then 365 days so answer 1000 days is Correct. @deceze

Comment: Well, no, those timestamps are in milliseconds and not in the 20th century, you're merely witnessing a number overflow. They're just a day apart.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below examples.

```
$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Or you can try below.

```
$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";
$datediff = $date2 - $date1;

echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: Not all years have 365 days.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$checkin_from = 1502143200000;
$reserve_to = 1502229600000;
$diff = $checkin_from - $reserve_to;
$days = abs($diff/86400*1000);
print $days;
```

86400 is an amount of seconds in one day

Comment: This will screw up because the original values are in milliseconds, but you're calculating in seconds.

Comment: @deceze thanks, I edited the message to make it right.